# Spring Security and users without username and password

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have two types of users: "common" and "social". "Common" type of users have email and password hash which i can associate with Spring Security UserDetails like this

```
public static class CommonUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    CommonUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPasswordHash();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    ...
```

I haven't problems with this type of users. But "Social" type of users haven't any email and password, they just have id in my database and id of assigned social network. Now i can identify user only by id of my app, so principal of each user will be id.

**First question**: is it good idea make identifier as principal of each user?

**Second question**: how can i adapt Authentication class to case of "social" user type? If principal would be id, what should be credentials?

Comment: Not sure if your code is just an example, but you should return an empty collection from `getAuthorities()` instead of returning `null`.